# Argument of type 'Element | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | VirtualElement'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Just struggling to understand how to correctly type this as I am getting the following error when trying to use the popper component. The documentation isn't clear and I don't have much Typescript experience.

> Argument of type 'Element | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | VirtualElement'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | VirtualElement'.ts(2345)
> const popcorn: Element | null

```
const popcorn = document.querySelector('#popcorn')
const tooltip = document.querySelector('#tooltip')

createPopper(popcorn, tooltip, {
  placement: 'top',
})
```

Comment: Since the elements you are searching for with `querySelector()` might not exist (as far as the *compiler* is concerned), naturally its return type is `Element | null` rather than just `Element`. And, well, `createPopper()` apparently doesn't accept a null argument, so it won't accept an `Element | null`, which could be null. If *you* are sure the elements exist, then you can use [the non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) on your first and second lines, which will coerce the types to `Element`.

Answer (score 2):

The `createPopper` function wants to make sure `popcorn` and `tooltip` are both actually elements. Since `querySelector` can return `null` (if no element is present), just check to make sure `popcorn` and `tooltip` are not null before calling `createPopper` on them.

```js
const popcorn = document.querySelector('#popcorn')
const tooltip = document.querySelector('#tooltip')

if (popcorn && tooltip) {
  createPopper(popcorn, tooltip, { placement: 'top' })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Nick. That makes sense. One more thing though. I'm not getting a Type error on 'tooltip' haha. 

Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.
  Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 107 more.ts(2345)

Was wondering if you could explain this one as well ? Thanks mate

Comment: I don't have a great answer for _why_, but it [looks like getElementById returns a type HTMLElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4793), which is narrower than `Element`. So I would recommend changing your second line to `const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip')`

Answer (score 1):

try passing it as

```
(popcorn as Element)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const popcorn = document.querySelector<HTMLDIVElemnt>('#popcorn')
const tooltip = document.querySelector<HTMLDIVElemnt>('#tooltip')

if (popcorn && tooltip) {
  createPopper(popcorn, tooltip, { placement: 'top' })
}
```

Use `<HTMLButtonELement>` if the target is a button
This should solve your issue